# Numerical Differentiation in python

Tags: python

I want to find derivative or gradient of a multi variable function in python like

`f(x,y)=3*sin(0.5+0.25*x*y)*cos(x)`

I have found some interesting answers using sympy for single variable defining variable as symbols

```
import sympy

x = sympy.symbol('x')

def f(x):

    return (x-3)*x**3*(x-6)**4

u = f(x)

print('f(x) = ',u)

g = [u.diff(x)]

print('grad f(x) = ',g)
```

but i want something for two variables where i can put values of (x,y) in the derivative and get the result printed in the numerical value. can please someone help me in this(for example if i want g(3)=0)

Comment: If you have a closed form reprsentation of your function, the laziest you can do is finite differences.

Comment: it should be `x = sympy.symbol.Symbol('x')`